# Namespaces with Phalcon models

Tags: php, phalcon

I have a project made with the command `phalcon project simple --type=simple`.

I haven't changed the structure at all.

The part where I'm stumped, is that I have two databases I look at.

I want to access the **Account** model for both databases **A** and **B**, with out doing something like `$account = AAccount::find();` and `$account = BAccount::find();`.

I currently have this code:

**model/AAccount.php**

```
class AAccount extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    // use DB A
}
```

**model/BAccount.php**

```
class BAccount extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    // use DB B
}
```

What is the most optimum way of doing so? Namespaces? I cannot change the table name **Account** for both.

Comment: Definitely Namespaces. Also if you haven't seen in the documentation for multiple databases in a project. http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#setting-multiple-databases

Comment: +1 for namespaces. They are a good idea to use anyway, but I've had this exact same use case before and had no snags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question: you have two tables with the same name, but they are in two different schemas (databases)? If yes, I had the same problem and I solve it with the follow structure (you can see part of this code in my [bauhaus project](https://github.com/fefaso/bauhaus-server-api)) (see this reference too: [point to other schema (Phalcon - Working with Model)](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#pointing-to-a-different-schema)):

(1) Base model class located at `models/`:

```
namespace MyApp\Model;

class Base extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
     // code for your model base class
}
```

(2) Base class for schema A located at `models/schema-a/`:

```
namespace MyApp\Model\SchemaA;

class Base extends MyApp\Model\Base
{
    // ...

    // returns the name of the schema A
    public function getSchema()
    {
        return `schema_a_name`;
    }

    // ...
}
```

(3) Base class for schema B located at `models/schema-b/`:

```
namespace MyApp\Model\SchemaB;

class Base extends MyApp\Model\Base
{
    // ...

    // returns the name of the schema B
    public function getSchema()
    {
        return `schema_b_name`;
    }

    // ...
}
```

(4) Account Model in the schema A located at `models/schema-a/`:

```
namespace MyApp\Model\SchemaA;

class Account extends Base
{
    // ...
}
```

(5) Account Model in the schema B located at `models/schema-b/`:

```
namespace MyApp\Model\SchemaB;

class Account extends Base
{
    // ...
}
```

This solution works good when you have a **fixed number of schemas**, but If you have *no-fixed* number of schemas, I think a better solution would be to create an logic in the `getSchema` function of the model base. Something like:

```
public function getSchema()
{
    // this is just a suggest
    return $this->getDI()->scope->currentSchema;
}
```

I hope this can help you.

*Note: you will have to be careful to create relationships between models with namespace.*